# ValueError: Error when checking target: expected dense_22 to have shape (100, 50) but got array with shape (1, 50)

Tags: python, machine-learning, keras, nlp, tf-idf

I'm training a neural network to predict the Document-Frequency from a set of documents.

So, the main idea is to map a matrix with 100 documents and 50 tokens to the respective document-frequency array.

X = (n_samples, 100, 50) -> y = (n_samples, 1, 50)

My code is:

```
model = Sequential()
model.add(Dense(50, activation='sigmoid', input_shape=(100,50)))
model.add(Dense(50))
model.compile(optimizer='rmsprop', loss='mse')
model.fit(X_train, y_train, epochs=50)
```

But i got an error:

```
ValueError: Error when checking target: expected dense_22 to have shape (100, 50) but got array with shape (1, 50)
```

Comment: Have you tried ``model.fit((X_train, y_train), epochs=50)``

Comment: model.fit parameters must be 2 different sets of data: training and testing, not a tuple.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That is because your input is two-dimensional so that your model summary is as follows.

```
_________________________________________________________________
Layer (type)                 Output Shape              Param #   
=================================================================
dense_1 (Dense)              (None, 100, 50)           2550      
_________________________________________________________________
dense_2 (Dense)              (None, 100, 50)           2550      
=================================================================
Total params: 5,100
Trainable params: 5,100
Non-trainable params: 0
_________________________________________________________________
```

Try to reshape the tensor shape after `dense_1` or `dense_2` by taking sum/average over the second axis to get the same shape as your `Y`.

**Here is my example for your reference**

I wrote a customized sum function to sum up over the second axis to make the tensor of (None, 100, 50) be (None, 1, 50). Then, add another Dense layer.

```py
import keras.backend as K
from keras.layers import Dense, Lambda
from keras.models import Sequential

def mysum(x): 
    return  K.sum(x, axis=1, keepdims=True) 

def mysum_output_shape(input_shape): 
    shape = list(input_shape) 
    print(shape)
    shape[1] = 1 
    return tuple(shape) 

# randomly generate data
import numpy as np
X_train = np.random.normal(0, 1, (50,100,50))
y_train = np.ones((50, 1, 50))

model = Sequential()
model.add(Dense(50, activation='sigmoid', input_shape=(100,50)))
model.add(Lambda(mysum, output_shape=mysum_output_shape)) 
model.add(Dense(50))
model.compile(optimizer='rmsprop', loss='mse')
model.fit(X_train, y_train, epochs=50)
```

It is important to know what your input is and how tensors are transformed through every layer. Hope this helps!